# Catching a NumberFormatException from an AlertDialog input

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to catch a NumberFormatException from an AlertDialog if a user enters a number larger than the Integer datatype can handle. I have tried the following code but i found no success. I am trying to catch the exception in the setOnItemClickListener method.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) throws RuntimeException{
            try{
            builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(IzbiraHrane.this);
            builder.setTitle("Enter your quantity");

            // Set up the input
            final EditText input = new EditText(IzbiraHrane.this);
            // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            builder.setView(input);

            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    kolicina = input.getText().toString();
                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    returnIntent.putExtra("kolicina",kolicina);
                    returnIntent.putExtra("id",id_ji.get(position));
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });


            builder.show();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(IzbiraHrane.this, "something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am also new to Android and Java so please consider this in your answer :)

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw  That is what i understood when i saw NumberFormatException on android studio when the error occurs. Then what  exception would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to catch the NumberFormatException

why not process the result in your `alertDialog` and handle the Exception.

try this code:

```
int number = 0;  //declare varible

    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            try {
                if(input.getString().toString().Trim().lenght()>0)  //not empty
                {
                    if(Integer.parseInt(input.gettext().toString()) <= 100000 )  //your Int bounds
                    {
                        kolicina = input.getText().toString();
                        number = Integer.parseInt(kolicina);
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                        returnIntent.putExtra("kolicina",kolicina);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("id",id_ji.get(position));
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }
    });
```

here you can process the `edittext` output string to check if it is in your required bounds..and also can catch the `Exception` easily.

Comment: I wrote the same. Nevertheless your answer us correct

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to catch a NumberFormatException from an AlertDialog if a
>   user enters a number larger than the Integer data type can handle.

you could use the **[Math.toIntExact()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-)** method in order to check whether there is integer overflow/underflow.

Example, something along the lines of this:

```
try {
    int myValue = Math.toIntExact(Long.parseLong(kolicina));
    // do something 
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
     // if it gets here then there is integer overflow/underflow.
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
     // if it gets here then the data entered is not a valid number.
}
```

> **[Math.toIntExact()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-)** - Returns the value of the long argument; throwing
>   an exception if the value overflows an int.

Comment: Unfortunatly my app is set to minimum API 9 and Math.toIntExcact() requires API 24 or so I understand. Thanks for your time :)